# System.Version doesn't implement System.IComparable in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, icomparable, base-class-library

I want to sort a sequence of `Version` objects in F#:

```ml
let maxVersion =
    versions
    |> Seq.max (fun version -> version)
```

The compiler produces the following error message:

> The type '(seq -> 'a)' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface

When I hit F12 in Visual studio to take a look at the metadata of `Version` it says that `Version` only implements `ICloneable`, but not `IComparable`. But when I go to [sourceof.net](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs,0c15515dfe051d35) it says it implements `IComparable` as well as some other interfaces.

Does F# use a different version of the .NET framework?

Comment: FYI, your `(fun version -> version)` could be replaced by `id` (if it was needed)

Comment: Oh yeah, this could be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `(seq->'a)` does not implement `IComparable` which is true since `(seq->'a)` is a function, not a sequence.

If you look at the signature of `Seq.max` it takes only the sequence as parameter.
Remove the lambda `(fun version -> version)` and it should be alright.

Otherwise, if you want to apply a key generator function for the sort, use instead `Seq.maxBy`

Comment: Ohh. That was almost too easy. Thanks.