# Explicitly stating a type in list comprehension that uses List.zip

Tags: f#

I have got the following list comprehension

```
member this.a l1 = 
        let res = [for x, y in List.zip l1 this.l2 do if y > 0 then yield (x |> double)/(y |> double) else yield 0.]
```

and I get the error

> The type '(float -> float)' does not support the 'comparison'
>   constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable'
>   interface
>
> This expression was expected to have type     float -> float     but
>   here has type     int

at the `y > 0` expression.

Is there a way to instruct the compiler, that `x` and `y` is a certain type, or that the `l1` and `l2` are of the same type?

**EDIT:**
What I actually have is `a` inside a class, updated to reflect that fact.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me if l1 and l2 are both int lists. Could you show how l1 and l2 are declared in your code?

Comment: If I set the `l1` and `l2` variables to `int list`, your snippet works in my F# interactive window. ([Also, here in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TnwJZa))

Comment: From the error it looks like `l2` is actually a list of functions `float -> float` instead of a list of ints.

Comment: By chance, are you doing something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524101/system-version-doesnt-implement-system-icomparable-in-f/27524181#27524181) after that line?

Comment: Assuming that @Lee is wrong (I don't think he is though...), you can specify types like so: `[for (y:int) in 1..10 -> y]`.  This is a good way to track down your error though.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you create a named value, you can specify the type like so: `y:int`.  For example: `[for y:int in 1..10 -> y]`.

As noted in the comments, I don't think that will resolve your issue, but it will probably help you narrow down what bit of your source is to blame.  A likely culprit is your definition of `l2`.  I'm guessing you are defining it using a function taking multiple parameters, but failed to supply sufficient parameters resulting in a function of type `float->float` instead of just a `float`.